# PHP date difference calculate onlys for days

Tags: php, datediff

My date is in format `day::month::year-h-m-s` now I want to take difference between these 2 dates only in days?

Comment: Show us real code and this kind of question available at stack,search for the solution first.

Comment: try this 

`$diff=date_diff(date_create($date1),date_create($date2));
echo  $diff->format("%a days");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php

$otherday = date_create("01-05-2015");
$today= date_create(date("d-m-Y"));

$days = $today->diff($otherday);

echo $days->format("%R%a");

?>
```

%R means (+) or (-) you can use only %a.

Answer (score 1):

**you can do this way**

```
  $date1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2013-08-07 13:00:00")));
  $date2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2013-08-08 12:00:00")));
  echo $date1->diff($date2)->days;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$dateDiff=date_diff(date_create($date1),date_create($date2)); 
echo $dateDiff->format("%a days");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$fisrstDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fisrstDate)));
$secondDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($secondDate)));
echo $fisrstDate->diff($secondDate)->days;
```